# Play2 route dynamic part not as method parameter

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0

In general we write route with parameter in this style

```
GET  /clients/:clientId/info              Controllers.Application.client(clientId)
```

In some case, I don't need clientId within method Application.client(), I hope I can write the entry as this way

```
GET /clients/:clientId/info               Controllers.Application.client()
```

for example, I want to get clientId by parsing the url.

In other word, hope url pattern /clients/[^/]+/info go to Application.client() method.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't omit usage of route parameters. The route parser will prevent you from skipping them.

You have to provide a method which will accept a parameter.

```
GET        /clients/:clientId/info        Controllers.Application.client(clientId)
```

If you really need a method with parameterless signature all you can do is forwarding a request from a method with a parameter.

You didn't write which language you are using. In Scala it would look as follows:

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def client(id: String): Action[AnyContent] = client()

  def client() = Action {
    Ok("")
  }

}
```

And for Java:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result client(String id) {
        return client();
    }

    public static Result client() {
        return ok();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use two different routes with the same method `GET` and path `/clients/:clientId/info` - that's obvious - how router should guess that path `/clients/foo/info` should be routed to other action than `/clients/bar/info`???

it's a task for your `Application.client(clientId)` action